# Reduce noise/too many labels on x axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot variables avg prices and model names. But there are too many values causing overlap. I need to have every name and cannot remove a certain label or omit it. There area a total of 1900 labels.

My data:

[image]
`dput(avgprice)`: https://pastebin.com/QmnDUQnp

```
    ggplot(avgprice, aes(x=modelname, y=average.price)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",width=0.5) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))+ 
      labs(y = "price", x ="model (bindwidth=40)", title = "averge price of cars")
```

Comment: please provide sample data using dput(avgprice)

Comment: you can orient the xaxis labels using: `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, size=4))`

Comment: added sample data

Comment: Please use ``dput(avgprice)`` to share your data rather than an images. Images make it hard for people to reproduce your issue and have a tendency to break after a while. Thanks.

Comment: You could try making the labels much smaller ``theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=3))``

Comment: still need to try and make it readable. Ideal solution would be to greatly increase the distance between labels and bars. M on size= 0.5 and eeh. Not looking good

Comment: The best solution seems to better orient the labels as suggested by @monte but who's going to be able to read 1900 labels? If this is for Shiny app or some sort of digital media, perhaps consider using a interactive plot that would display the label when hovering. If it's static, perhaps at table would be a better choice

Comment: Another suggestion is to swap the x and y-axes, at least then the labels are in the natural reading direction. You might also consider labelling only some of the data you care about. Also, is the intended audience of your plot really going to skip through 1900 labels to lookup some particular ones they might care about?

Comment: tru! thanks for all the help guys